# Reload? Javascript after Jquery .live/.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, load, live

I wanted to load some fragments of external content inside a div, through a menu.

Found "load" and "live", found a [tutorial](http://www.wpmods.com/easily-ajax-wordpress-pagination/) used it = success!
Except, like what's explicit in the documentation, it doesn't load JavaScript.

The thing is, the destination page already loads, inside the header, that same JavaScript, 'cause Wordpress loads it in every page. In this particular page, I'm only using the plugin (nextgen gallery) through the jQuery AJAX call.

So, what I believe is my problem is that I somehow need to alert/reload the JavaScript, right?

And how can I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    // ajax pagination
    jQuery('#naveg a').live('click', function(){ // if not using wp-page-numbers, change this to correct ID
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                    // #main is the ID of the outer div wrapping your posts
        jQuery('#fora').html('<div class="loading"><h2>Loading...</h2></div>');
                    // #entries is the ID of the inner div wrapping your posts
        jQuery('#fora').load(link+' #dentro')
    return false;   
    }); 
}); // end ready function
</script>
```

PS: I've substituted "live" with "on" but didn't work either.

Comment: Bro tip: You can use `$` in place of `jQuery` to save typing time and screen space :-)

Comment: @JamWaffles: _Bro_ tip?!

Comment: Thanks but I believe I can't do that 'cause it will generate a conflict :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand... your load() command is puling in some Javascript that you want executed? I'm not sure if you can do that. But if you just need to call some JS upon load() completion, you can pass it a function like so:

```
jQuery('#fora').load(link+' #dentro', function() {
    console.log("load completed");
    // JS code to be executed...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The necessary javascript for the loaded content to work properly is already loaded in the landing page header but it's like it isn't triggered for the new elements

Comment: The JS code to be inserted in your suggestion is like <script type... src... bla bla bla>?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute Javascript code included in the loaded page (the page you retrieve via .load()), than you have to use the url-parameter without the "suffixed selector expression". See jQuery documentation for ([.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)):

> **Note:** When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is however called with a selector expression appended to the
>   URL, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   which is why they are never executed. An example of both cases can be
>   seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will
>   successfully execute.
>
> ```
> $('#a').load('article.html');
> ```
>
> However in this case, script blocks in the document being loaded into
>   #b are stripped out prior to being executed:
>
> ```
> $('#b').load('article.html #target');
> ```

I think that's your problem (although I have no solution for you, sorry).

Proposal: Maybe you can load the whole page (including the Scripts) and remove (or hide) the parts you don't need?

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but although I don't know how to pull everything and then "filter", I believe that would be an overkill, since it's a menu and will pull different content several times. I've read what you said before coming here. I thought there was some kind of success function or whatever that could reload or wake up the already loaded javascript in header of landing page.